# Quel sens de 'coucher' ?

Tags: vocabulaire

In *Robin des bois*, there's a scene where Prince John has called his rhinoceros guards to his aid, but they end up charging directly at him. He thus shouts:

> Rhinocéros, halte ! Arrêtez ! Couchés !

In English, this is "Halt! Stop! Desist!"

Which sense of *coucher* / *couché* is meant here? Is it a military term, e.g. "stand down", "at ease"? Or perhaps just "get down", "get on the ground"? I can't find a clear reference to it on WordReference or CNRTL.

[image: Rhinocéros, halte ! Arrêtez ! Couchés !]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Couché !*** (literally: "Lie down!") is an order typically given to a dog to tell him to stop moving, to lie down on the ground.

Along with *Couché*, you'll hear *Assis !*, *Debout !* and *Donne la patte !* as basic dog training commands.

Prince John talks to his rhinos as if they were pets.

Comment: Nice. A good joke added in translation, even if the tone is quite different from "desist"!